# setEnabled Not working on UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I disable a button with `[myButton setEnabled: NO]`. Then, I try to enable it with `[myButton setEnabled: YES]`. And nothing happens. Do I forgot something?

Comment: Need more code, like what the button does, how its used, etc.

Comment: I am making a time calculator. I have three buttons for hours, minutes and seconds respectively. I disable each one when is pressed so users cannot make a bad entry. When user presses a button like '+', '-', or '=', I need to enable it again. I attached an IBAction these buttons to achieve what I need. No success. The IBActions simply calls setEnabled:. Very simple, I didn't paste the code for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out your interface builder, maybe forgot to hook up your button to the outlet..

Comment: I'm updating a label with a random number when the code is supposed to activate de buttons. The label is updated but the buttons remains disabled.

Comment: @TeofiloIsraelVizcainoRodrig: So check what Dor Bashan suggested: Is the outlet connected to the button?

Comment: Hello, they wasn't connected. I was so tired that was confusing IBActions with IBOutlets :S. After connect the buttons to the outlets it worked fine. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code you are describing to enable the button is correct.  The next thing to check would be if that code is actually getting called, or if, for some reason, the code never reaches that line.